# Handle EXC_BAD_ACCESS for UnsafePointer in Swift

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

How I can handle `EXC_BAD_ACCES`.

This is my Code:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "9953240D-41CF-4F4E-8C82-EE75E6D43B6B" {
        let value = characteristic.value!.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>) -> Int in
            return pointer.pointee
    }
    print ("VALUE 1: \(value)")
}
```

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xbad0) In line "return pointer.pointee"

Comment: Have you verified that `characteristic.value` is not `nil`? – What does `print(characteristic.value! as NSData)` show?

Comment: print(characteristic.value! as NSData) Retruns:  <>

Comment: I think its 0 bytes

Comment: Indeed. And that's why it crashes.

Comment: How I can check its nil?         if (characteristic.value == nil){
            print ("nil")
        } Don't work

Comment: `Data` has a `count` which you can check.